# Problem about the definition of convergence in measure

Tags: measure-theory

I'm looking at the definition of convergence in measure. How can I prove that the set $\{x\in E\, |\,|{f}_n(x)-{f}(x)|\geq \delta \}$ is measurable? Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of measurable function? $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ is a measurable function if $f_n$ and $f$ are measurable, so it might just be the definition of measurability.

Comment: You can't prove that in general, without some assumption on $f$: let $A$ be a nonmeasurable set, and let $f_n(x) = 1/n$ for $x \in A$, and $0$ otherwise. Then the zero-function $f$ is the limit of the $f_n$, but the set you've described, for $\delta = 1/(2n)$, is exactly $A$, which is not measurable.

Comment: @John But is the pointwise convergence also convergence in measure? Since the $f_n$ are non-measurable functions...

Comment: Agreed...but nothing at all was said about the $f_n$ and $f$ in the question; my point was that without such assumptions, it's easy to craft examples where the set was nonmeasurable, even when you had pointwise convergence...perhaps that latter thing was a red herring. I didn't mean to confuse anyone.